# Can't export just a part of my aspx page on C#

Tags: c#, excel, export

I am trying to export just a table that is contained on my page. I have some filters above it but when exporting, all the text and filters are copied into this file.

This is the code:

```
tableCreateOrders a = new tableCreateOrders(dtReportColumns, 2, 10);
divResult.Controls.Add(a.displayTable());
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=orders.xls");
Response.Write(a.displayTable());
```

`a.displayTable()` is the object containing the table, but the filters are defined on the .aspx so there is no way the command take it. Is there anything I am doing wrong? I'll really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need. Remember to **ClearContent** before and **End** after.

```
Response.ClearContent(); 

Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"; 
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=orders.xls");

Response.Write(a.DisplayTable());

Response.End();
```

Comment: Thanks! It made a lot of sense. But when I did that, I got an excel file but it just contains this line:
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable
This is the code again:
Response.ClearContent();
tableCreateOrders a = new tableCreateOrders(dtReportColumns, 2, 10);
divResult.Controls.Add(a.displayTable());
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=orders.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.Write(a.displayTable());
Response.End();
I really appreciate your help. Definitely have to mark your solution as an answer.